# How to find values $h,k$ such that $T$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2?$

Tags: statistics, expectation, estimation

Let $(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a realization of a random vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$ where $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$ for all $i$ and $Cov(X_i,X_j)=\rho$ for all $i \neq j$.
Further let $$T(x_1,...,x_n):=h\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 + k(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2$$ be an estimator for $\sigma^2$. How can I find values of $h,k \in \mathbb R $ such that $T$ is unbiased?

Comment: Well, guessing by whats given, you could set $E(T)=Var(X_1)$ and solve for $h,k$. It might help to remember some well known formulas for $(X_1+\dotso+X_n)^2$, $Var(X)$ and $Cov(X_i,X_j)$....

Comment: $E(T)=\sigma^2$, $E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2$, $(X_1+X_2+\dots +X_n)^2=\sum_i X^2_i+\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j$. I think these results may help.

Comment: @MANMAID are you sure about your multinomial formula? Aren't you missing a factor of 2 in the second sum? say, $n=2$ then, $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy\neq x^2+y^2 +xy$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I wrote $i\neq j$, it includes both $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$.

Comment: @MANMAID Right. Sorry, I was thinking of $\sum_{i<j}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\rho = 0$ you'll get the coefficients for the "regular" sample variance formula, that is 
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum (X_i - \bar{X}_n)
$$
Just use the properties of expectation and the definition of variance, i.e., 
\begin{align}
ET =& h E\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 + k E(n\bar{X}_n)^2 = hn(Var(X) + E^2(X)) + kn^2(Var(\bar{X}_n) +  E^2(\bar{X}_n))\\
 =& hn(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) +kn^2\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + kn^2\mu^2 = \sigma^2 (n k + hn) + n\mu^2 (h+kn) = \sigma^2.
\end{align}
So by equating coefficients we get 
$$
nk + hn=1, \quad h+kn=0
$$
hence, $h=\frac{1}{n-1}$ and $k=-\frac{1}{n^2 -n}$.

---

For $\rho \neq 0$ note that 
$$
Var(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}(n \sigma^2 + (n^2-n)\rho) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n}\rho,
$$
thus
\begin{align}
ET =& h E\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 + k E(n\bar{X}_n)^2 = hn(Var(X) + E^2(X)) + kn^2(Var(\bar{X}_n) +  E^2(\bar{X}_n))\\
 =& hn(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) +kn^2(\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n} \rho - \mu^2)\\ 
=& \sigma^2(hn+kn) + \mu^2n(h-kn) + k(n^2-n)\rho
\end{align}
thus the two equations to b solved w.r.t $k$ and $h$ are
$$
hn + kn =1, \quad \mu^2n(h-kn) + k(n^2-n)\rho = 0
$$
where $k=1-h$ and $h = 1 -  \frac{\mu^2}{2\mu^2 - (n-1)\rho}$.
Please check the calculations in the final raw. Cannot guarantee they have no typos.

Comment: A standard formula for sample variance is $S^2 = \frac{\sum X_i^2 - (\sum_i X_i)^2/n}{n-1}.$

Comment: Right. And there are more elegant ways to find this unbiased estimator than that in the question.